# How to redirect stdout to a file without the content displaying in the terminal?

Tags: stdout

`tee` shows the stdout in terminal, I don't want it to do that but cant find an option

```
          || visible in terminal ||   visible in file   || existing
  Syntax  ||  StdOut  |  StdErr  ||  StdOut  |  StdErr  ||   file   
==========++==========+==========++==========+==========++===========
    >     ||    no    |   yes    ||   yes    |    no    || overwrite
    >>    ||    no    |   yes    ||   yes    |    no    ||  append
          ||          |          ||          |          ||
   2>     ||   yes    |    no    ||    no    |   yes    || overwrite
   2>>    ||   yes    |    no    ||    no    |   yes    ||  append
          ||          |          ||          |          ||
   &>     ||    no    |    no    ||   yes    |   yes    || overwrite
   &>>    ||    no    |    no    ||   yes    |   yes    ||  append
          ||          |          ||          |          ||
 | tee    ||   yes    |   yes    ||   yes    |    no    || overwrite
 | tee -a ||   yes    |   yes    ||   yes    |    no    ||  append
          ||          |          ||          |          ||
 n.e. (*) ||   yes    |   yes    ||    no    |   yes    || overwrite
 n.e. (*) ||   yes    |   yes    ||    no    |   yes    ||  append
          ||          |          ||          |          ||
|& tee    ||   yes    |   yes    ||   yes    |   yes    || overwrite
|& tee -a ||   yes    |   yes    ||   yes    |   yes    ||  append
```

Comment: AFAIK the `tee` command doesn't have such an option - but you can simply redirect stdout to /dev/null (`> /dev/null`) if you don't want it to be displayed in the terminal

Comment: Why use `tee` at all?  Doesn't standard `>` redirection do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

[Please edit your question; the title makes no sense, as that could be done with the simple `> file` redirection from the first row]

The missing rows could be done in **bash** with the `2> >(...)` and `> >(...)` redirection + process substitution combinations.

E.g. for the most useful case (see full table at the end):

```
# both stderr+stdout to the tty, only stderr to the file
$ ls -d /etc /etx 2> >(tee file)
/etc
ls: cannot access '/etx': No such file or directory

$ cat file
ls: cannot access '/etx': No such file or directory
```

Notice though that `> >(...)` tends to be tricky and buggy. Even when working fine, the stdout and stderr may come mixed up, or after the prompt:

```
bash$ sh -c 'sleep .1; ls -d /etc /etx' 2> >(tee errors)
ls: cannot access '/etx'/etc
: No such file or directory

bash$ ls -d /etc /etx 2> >(sleep .1; tee errors)
/etc
bash$ ls: cannot access '/etx': No such file or directory
```

---

Portably, it could be done by swapping the stdout and stderr with `3>&2 2>&1 >&3 3>&-`:

```
$ ls -d /etc /etx 3>&1 >&2 2>&3 3>&- | cat | tee file
ls: cannot access '/etx': No such file or directory
/etc

$ cat file
ls: cannot access '/etx': No such file or directory
```

Note: the "useless" cat is needed in order to dodge around tee's input buffering; `stdbuf -i0 tee file` should work too. Having the different outputs mixed up will *always* be a problem when you have multiple processes writing to the same place, which afaik cannot be fixed without intercepting the actual `fprintf` and similar calls within the application itself.

---

**Tables**

The appending forms were omitted; you can easily get them by replacing `tee file` with `tee -a file` and `>file` with `>>file`. The `... tee /dev/fd/3 ... 3 >&1 or 3>&2 ...` commands could be simplified to `tee /dev/tty` if they're only intended to be run from an interactive terminal.

**bash**

```
TERMINAL      FILE
OUT  ERR    OUT  ERR
yes  yes    yes  yes     cmd |& tee file
yes  yes    yes   no     cmd | tee file
yes  yes     no  yes     cmd 2> >(tee file)
yes  yes     no   no     cmd
yes   no    yes  yes     (cmd | tee /dev/fd/3) 3>&1 &>file
yes   no    yes   no     cmd 2>/dev/null | tee file
yes   no     no  yes     cmd 2>file
yes   no     no   no     cmd 2>/dev/null
 no  yes    yes  yes     (cmd 2> >(tee /dev/fd/3)) 3>&2 &>file
 no  yes    yes   no     cmd >file
 no  yes     no  yes     cmd 2> >(tee file) >/dev/null
 no  yes     no   no     cmd >/dev/null
 no   no    yes  yes     cmd &>file
 no   no    yes   no     cmd >file 2>/dev/null
 no   no     no  yes     cmd >/dev/null 2>file
 no   no     no   no     cmd &>/dev/null
```

**Standard /bin/sh**

```
TERMINAL      FILE
OUT  ERR    OUT  ERR
yes  yes    yes  yes     cmd 2>&1 | tee file
yes  yes    yes   no     cmd | tee file
yes  yes     no  yes     cmd 3>&2 2>&1 >&3 3>&- | tee file
yes  yes     no   no     cmd
yes   no    yes  yes     (cmd | tee /dev/fd/3) 3>&1 >file 2>&1
yes   no    yes   no     cmd 2>/dev/null | tee file
yes   no     no  yes     cmd 2>file
yes   no     no   no     cmd 2>/dev/null
 no  yes    yes  yes     (cmd 4>&2 2>&1 >&4 4>&- | tee /dev/fd/3) 3>&1 >file 2>&1
 no  yes    yes   no     cmd >file
 no  yes     no  yes     cmd 2>&1 >/dev/null | tee file
 no  yes     no   no     cmd >/dev/null
 no   no    yes  yes     cmd >file 2>&1
 no   no    yes   no     cmd >file 2>/dev/null
 no   no     no  yes     cmd >/dev/null 2>file
 no   no     no   no     cmd >/dev/null 2>&1
```